# Bootstrap navbar logo height and menu dividers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

At this moment I am busy with making a nav exactly like this: 
[image]

Right now I have made this:
[image]

How can I fix that logo and dividers like the first image?
I make the website with Bootstrap and I have add some elements you see below in

```css
html, body{
}


nav{
    background:#fff;
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 30px;
}

.navbar-header{
    display:block; 
    text-align:center;
    height:80px;
}

    .navbar-header img{
        margin:0px auto;
        height:45px;
    }

    a.navbar-brand{
        padding:20px 30px; 
        position: absolute; 
        width:auto; 
        left:0; 
        top:0; 
        text-align:center; 
        margin:auto;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .navbar-collapse.collapse{
        padding:0px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .navbar{
        background:#fff;
        width:100%; 
        margin:0px;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        z-index:10; 
        border: 0px solid transparent;
        border-radius:0px
    }

    .navbar > div{
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
    }


    .collapse, .nabar-right{
        margin-right: 0px!important;
    }

        .navbar ul li a{
            background:none; 
            text-transform:uppercase; 
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight:300; 
            font-size:14px; 
            color:#000; 
            letter-spacing: 0.035em;
            text-decoration: none;
        }



ul.nav li.open ul.dropdown-menu li{
             padding:0px 0px;
        }

        .navbar ul li a:hover{
            background:#ffffff; 
            color:#22257a!important;
        }

        .navbar ul li a:active{
            background:none;
        }

.nav-selected{color:#22257a!important; font-weight:700;}
.navbar a.nav-selected{color:#22257a!important; font-weight:700;}
.navbar ul li.nav-path-selected .dropdown-toggle{color:#22257a;  font-weight:700;}
/*-------------------------------------------------*/

.caret {
    color: #000000;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s; /* Safari */
    transition: color 0.2s;
}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000000 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    border:1px solid #f1f1f1;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-top: -15px;
    padding:0px 0px;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    padding: 2px 16px 2px 16px;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus, .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    color: #777777 !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    padding: 8px 14px;
}


div#ccm-highlighter{z-index:1000; min-height:30px;}

hr {
    width: 120px;
    border-top: 4px solid black !important;
}

i {
    color: white;
}
.intro-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
}
header p{
    color:white;
}
header i {
    float:left; 
    padding-right: 10px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
<title>Title</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mobiel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/desktop.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="typography.css">
<link href='######' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--[if gte IE 9]><style type="text/css">.gradient {filter: none;}</style><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>


    <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="http://itavisen.no/wp-content/uploads/imported/5064692.jpg">
                </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>06 12345678</p>
    </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"> 
          <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i><p>@mail.nl</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>


    </header>
            <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar">

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                    <span>Menu</span>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">
                </button>

            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" class="nav-selected">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">page2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu arrow_box">
                            <li><a href="#">page1drop</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">page2drop</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">page3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page4</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </nav>
            </div>

<div class="intro-top">
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doe,

For the logo you may try z-index to put it in the front of the webpage.

And for the "li" you should use padding and border to get the same result.

If you want to practice by watching code you should find some bootstrap menu template.

e.g. : http://blog.themearmada.com/20-inspiring-bootstrap-menu-examples/

Comment: with z-index the logo will be in the front but I also want to the red background of the logo in the front. That doesn't work with: 

    a.navbar-brand {
        z-index: 99;
    }
The problem with adding a border for the li is this:
[enter image description here][1]
It doesn't end at the bottom but already halfway.


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GzLKQ.png